# can we mention more than one node label in single nodeSelector in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

i want to schedule 10 pods in two specific node(total 15 nodes in our kube cluster).

so in replication-controller file i am mentioning two values in nodeSelector
like below.

```
nodeSelector:  
  app: node1  
  app: node2
```

problem is that all the time it's taking only node2.whatever sequence i am  mentioning, it's taking last node only.

note: `node1` and `node2` are lables of node.

Answer (score 14):

The better way is in using something like this:

```
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
            - node1
            - node2
```

Comment: This will deploy pod in either of node1 or node2, not both

Comment: @karthik101 This will deploy pod in either of node1 or node2, or even both (i.e., one pod on each node) if replicas is set 2.

Answer (score 8):

The `nodeSelector` on a `PodSpec` is just a `map[string]string` (instead of the more featureful `NodeSelector` type that is used in the `NodeAffinity` object).That means that the key "app" can only have one value, and it ends up being overwritten as "node2".

You can accomplish the scheduling between node1 and node2 by applying a common label (e.g. `scheduling-group: foo`), and then have your replicationController use that label as the `nodeSelector`.

Comment: thanks for explaining.really helpful.can u explain little bitmore about scheduling-group

Comment: `scheduling-group` is just an example label key, you can specify any key that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

If you want the pods to be scheduled to either node1 or node2, you may label both nodes with the same label(s) (for example, `app=node`), and then add `app=node` as your `nodeSelector`. You can add as many labels as you want, but like CJ mentioned, `nodeSelector` is a map with key and value pairs so it can't have the same key with different values.

The pods can be scheduled on any of the nodes that satisfy that `nodeSelector`.

For more information, read [Assigning Pods to Nodes](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/). Note that there's a new feature called `nodeAffinity` that you might also want to try.

Comment: the question is clearly asking about a nodes w/ different label values, this answer is just valid if the user have admin permissions on this cluster and can change/update the node labels

Answer (score 1):

No cannot use the same key name for key/value pairs in YAML dictionaries. Use different keys. To schedule a pod to nodes labled with node:super or nodetype:duper:

```
spec:
  nodeSelector: { node: "super", nodetype: "duper" }
```

In YAML

```
martin:
  name: Martin D'vloper
  job: Developer
  skill: Elite
```

is the same with:

```
martin: {name: Martin D'vloper, job: Developer, skill: Elite}
```

If it can be one line, it is easier to manipulate.

Comment: Is the pod scheduled either 'node: "Super"' or 'nodetype: "dupler' ?  Or  The pod will be scheduled on the node where has both 'node:"super"', _AND_ 'nodetype:"duper"'?

Comment: It's an AND: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector

"... Kubernetes only schedules the Pod onto nodes that have each of the labels you specify."